# Need to create new database table in nopcommerce3.3 for Custom Plugin

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, e-commerce, nopcommerce

We are creating a new Custom Plugin in NopCommerce 3.3 and we are creating a new table in existing database for the same.

For that we have also followed all steps related to creating required classes and data base mappers in `Nop.Core Nop.Data respectively` , created Interface and implementing it in service class in `Nop.Service`.

Also we have made a entry in `DependencyRegistrar` Class and also manually created a table in database.

Works fine while working the reference in plugin and calling service methods for CRUD.

But after all these steps we are getting a Following error when routing to the Index View for the Plugin

`"Could not load type 'Nop.Services.BabyRegistry.IBabyRegistration' from assembly 'Nop.Services, Version=3.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'."`

`BabyRegistry` is our new Plugin created in Plugins Folder.

Any Help is most appreciated.

Comment: Why is BabyRegistry.IBabyRegistration located in Nop.Services, if you are creating a plugin? :)

Comment: I created IBabyRegistration interface and BabyRegistrationService to implement, inside Nop.Service class library to define the defination for CRUD operation on newly created table.
I followed what had been done previously with other tables (Entity classes) in NopCommerce DB following Nop.Core, Nop.Data, Nop.Service

Comment: Then what is the purpose of the plugin, if you are creating new classes in Nop.Services?

Comment: I'm new to NopCommerce development , I had a work to implement a custom Plugin to register baby Gifts and for this I had to add new database tables into the existing one , following what has been done with the current database tables I followed the same procedure.
I also tried a different approach from following link for a change.
 
tech.sunnyw.net/2013/12/nopcommerce-create-new-sql-table-domain.html

Answer (score 0):

This official manual will help you: http://www.nopcommerce.com/docs/75/plugin-with-data-access.aspx

And you shouldn't create any classes at the Libraries folder if you want to develope a plugin.